# ini_set() always returning false

Tags: php, security, session, ini-set

On my current project I have a security.php which holds up, some functions and some ini_set() statements.

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'whirlpool');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', '5');
```

So here is my problem. If I put some sort of check...

```
if(ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0) === false)
    echo "Foo!";
```

It always returns false, no matter which one I am trying to set.
I thought the problem was with the security.php permissions, but I was wrong.

EDIT

```
var_dump(ini_set('display_errors', '0'));
```

returns string(0) ""

Any other idea?

Thanks, Sebastian

Comment: Remove comma and 0 from if statement.  You assigned value there

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `ini_get`?

Comment: @Sebastian, interesting question. Can you check if ini_set works with other ini values?... for example: `var_dump(ini_set('display_errors', '0'));` ?

Comment: Is ini_set enabled/allowed to use? Can you ini_set anything (e.g. display_errors)? EDIT: If you call ini_get to get the values after ini_set are they not changed? Are you calling session_start() prior to the ini_sets?

Comment: var_dump(ini_set('display_errors', '0')); returns string(0) ""

Comment: @Sebastjan .. This means, that ini_set() basically works

Comment: Are you aware that `ini_set` returns the old value?

Comment: Tested, ini_get returns the same value before and after "changing".
@dirt session is active in the time of changing

Answer (score -3):

`ini_set` always returns a string, so this strict comparison will always be false:

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0) === false
```

If you want to check the value without changing it, use `ini_get`:

```
if (ini_get('session.use_trans_sid') == 0) ...
```

or

```
if (!ini_get('session.use_trans_sid')) ...
```

`ini_set` will set the value *and* return the previous value.

Comment: `ini_set` returns false when there is a failure, per the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php#refsect1-function.ini-set-returnvalues).